# BLE bluetooth connect error on Android 14

Tags: connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-14

I released **BLE** connecting and communicating App.
My App connects and communicates with HM-10 chips. It works on Android 13.
But error only occurs on version **Android 14**.
I checked the release note, but there seemed to be no mention of Bluetooth.
The error is as follows.
**"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is not a valid Bluetooth address."**
If anyone know about this error, please let me know.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Can you please share your code and the permission manifest file as this can help with understanding the issue.

Comment: Please share the code how you construct/get the BluetoothDevice object.